# Facebook OAuth2 does not provide user email

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, facebook-oauth

This has been asked many times but it seems like there's no known work-around for it so I'm posting this question in the hope that someone does have a work-around for it.

I'm using NodeJS, PassportJS-Facebook.

```
app.get("/auth/facebook",
            passport.authenticate("facebook", {
                scope : [ "email" ]
            }),
            function (req, res) {
            });
```

At first I thought it's a PassportJS issue but I certainly eliminated this option.
The Facebook user account I'm using clearly states:

```
This app needs: 
Your basic info
Your email address (xyz@example.com)
```

Some links to this known issue (yet unsolved!):
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298946933534016
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/429653750464521
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/482815835078469

So, do you use Facebook's OAuth service? If so, do you get the user's email? How? The "straight" way? A work-around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Facebook strategy in passportjs, expects a `profileFields` field in the options. Try passing "email" in the options.

`strategyOptions.profileFields = ['emails', 'first_name', 'last_name'];`

Alternatively, you can override the `profileUrl` in the `options` and send:

`strategyOptions.profileURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=location,first_name,last_name,middle_name,name,link,username,work,education,gender,timezone,locale,verified,picture,about,address,age_range,bio,birthday,cover,currency,devices,email,favorite_athletes,id,hometown,favorite_teams,inspirational_people,install_type,installed,interested_in,languages,meeting_for,name_format,political,quotes,relationship_status,religion,significant_other,sports,updated_time,website';`

Facebook will ignore fields that you don't have a permission to (like email).

This should go here:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback",
    profileUrl: "  ..... ",
    //or
    profileFields: [ ... ];
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {

      // To keep the example simple, the user's Facebook profile is returned to
      // represent the logged-in user.  In a typical application, you would want
      // to associate the Facebook account with a user record in your database,
      // and return that user instead.
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));
```

```

Comment: Not working, I already have: `profileFields : ["id", "name", "first_name", "last_name", "link", "username", "gender", "locale", "age_range", "displayName", "photos", "email"]`

Comment: Overriding the profileUrl option seems like a serious hack, which also implies an error in Passport itself..

Comment: I confirm that using profileUrl works, it does give me the email. I guess I'll open a bug in Passport-Facebook project.. Thanks Eugenio!

Comment: Just a follow up - it should be "emails", not "email".

Comment: Glad that it worked! Using 'emails' in profileFields should work too (emails not email, you are right). re: overriding profileUrl, not sure it is a serious hack or not. I don't like it either, but it is an extensibility option offered by the library. Good luck!

Comment: i wish i could just express my utmost gratitude for this elegant answer ... you really saved my project bro... while i had just a few hours to finalize facebook login

Answer (score 0):

You must provide field 'scope' in settings object:

```
new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback",
    profileUrl: "  ..... ",
    scope: "email",
    //or
    profileFields: [ ... ];
  }
```

try to look sources.